# TYPO3 Extension tx_news and articles proposed

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I want two articles proposed at the bottom of every news-article in the detail view.
But i don't know a solution for this task.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - with detailed sight to the backend and to "news" - i have found the solution. The point is the area "related news" behind the tab "relations".